# Proper way to insert relationships into Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have this core data model :

[image]

Sometimes, when I try to insert a "BoissonCave" element, my application crashes. This is where it happens (I'm reading data from the array "values" which contains JSON data) :

```
let boissonCave = BoissonCave(context: context)
[...]
if let _regionId = values["regionId"] as? Int16 {
    let region = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.getRegion(ofId: Int(_regionId))
    boissonCave.fromRegion = region
}
```

I'm getting different errors, either when Core Data fetches the "Region", or when I try to assign fromRegion of boissonCave. It's either

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'`

or even `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x174259c80> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

I suspect this is a context issue, where Core Data tries to fetch a Region in one context, and insert a BoissonCave in another ? How should I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [CoreDataStack](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/08/12/whats-new-core-data-swift-3-0/). Why don't you use 1 static core data stack? and create a child-context whenever needed. You can always merge changes to the child to the main context. This is a very slightly modified version from the url above that I have used since iOS 10.0

```
class CoreDataStack {

    static let shared = CoreDataStack()

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Almanapp")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    var context : NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func saveContext() {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `if let` syntax prevents `_regionId` to be nil, so that may not be the problem.

Comment: You are chaining 2 optionals. One is the value from the dictionary. That is always an optional because there might not be such value in the dictionary. The other is parsing it as? Int16 which is also optional. If let only replaces one of those. I will adapt my answer with a quick playground test for you.

Comment: I don't quite get where you're going. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but the `if let` syntax prevents the enclosed code to be executed if the value  after the `=` is, indeed, nil. In your playground example, [that's why your second `print` is never executed](http://i.imgur.com/JoGejTA.png). Same if you're looking for anything else that `"string"` in your `dict`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry, had to check it again. I've had some issues with optional chaining in the past and thought that casting and evaluating in the same if-let were the issue, I was wrong.

Comment: I have changed my answer reflecting other possibility of Core Data context being out of sync

Comment: Thanks. I already used this exact pattern though. I may have found a solution, which consists of adding several merging parameters to my CoreDataStack viewContext. Also, I added a `performAndWait` block before adding the `Region` and `SousRegion` managed objects. I had no crash since! I'll add this as a solution later, thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

So what did the trick was a combination of 2 things :

-First, I made sure that my `Region` and `SousRegion` objects were inserted before my `BoissonCave` objects by wrapping my insert code between a `context.performAndWait { ... }` (you must of course use the same context for both inserts)

-I added merging policies in my context as such :

```
lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    self.persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    try! self.persistentContainer.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)

    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()
```

I had no crash since.